# Page loading slowly in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using the colorbox on my site due to this the page is loading very slowly in IE as comparison to other browsers. When I remove the colorbox jQuery file the pages are loading fine. How can I resolve this? I am using the following scripts on my site:

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script> 
<?php if($_GET['s']=="invoices") {?>
   <script src="js/thickbox1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php } else {?>
   <script src="js/thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php }?> 
<script src="js/jquery.treeview.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Stop doing slow things on page load ? You've identified the slow script here, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Where are these `<script>` tags located in the HTML?

Comment: Can I suggest not using jQuery and writing your own damn code? Seriously, even the worst-written JavaScript I've ever seen is twice as fast as jQuery...

Comment: Kolink: that comment makes no sense.

Comment: these script tags located in the head tag

Answer (score 0):

You could try [defering](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/) script execution. This way it would be executed later, when the page is already loaded. Also, you can put it in the end of your HTML document, right before the closing `</body>` tag. The browser could then render most of the UI and only then load "colorbox".

Comment: I used defering but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option: Load your scripts via JavaScript on DOM ready.

Consider the following:

```
if (window.addEventListener) { // for non-crappy browsers
  window.addEventListener('load', loadHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // for IE
  window.attachEvent('onload', loadHandler);
}

function loadHandler() {
  var scripts = {
    'scripts': {
      'src': 'js/scripts.js',
      'type': 'text/javascript'
    },
    'jquery': {
      'src': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js',
      'type': ''
    },
    'colorbox': {
      'src': 'js/jquery.colorbox-min.js',
      'type': 'text/javascript'
    },

    'thickbox1': {
      'src': 'js/thickbox1.js',
      'type': 'text/javascript'
    },
    'thickbox': {
      'src': 'js/thickbox.js',
      'type': 'text/javascript'
    },
    'treeview': {
      'src': 'js/jquery.treeview.min.js',
      'type': 'text/javascript'
    },
    'tipTip': {
        'src': 'js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',
        'type': 'text/javascript'
    }
  };
  for (var key in scripts) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = scripts[key]['src'];
    script.type = scripts[key]['type'];
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

This way, your scripts will only load when the page is ready.

Comment: page loaded fast but colorbox and other functionality is not working

Comment: Do you have a test page that I could look at? On my test page, the console is showing that the browser is trying to load those resources.

Comment: Can you drop my script into `<head>` please? Don't put it within your `$(document).ready(function(){});` because of the load event listeners (or just remove those and call the `loadHandler()` function).

Comment: Thank you. It's because jQuery is not defined which makes sense considering it's not being called until just before `</body>`. So, the script in your header won't work because jQuery hasn't been defined yet. Put that inline script into your scripts.js file and you should be good to go.